# Search option in android

Tags: android, android-layout, search-engine

I am able to get search suggestions from list view.but i need too hide bottom suggestion them untill i type text in search box(as google search).In google when we type text then only it shows suggestions to the text we have typed.[image: Here is my code output image.]

Main Activity Code

```
    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    // List view
    private ListView lv;

    // Listview Adapter
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter;

    // Search EditText
    EditText inputSearch;


    // ArrayList for Listview
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> productList;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Listview Data
        String products[] = {"Dell Inspiron", "HTC One X", "HTC Wildfire S", "HTC Sense", "HTC Sensation XE",
                                "iPhone 4S", "Samsung Galaxy Note 800",
                                "Samsung Galaxy S3", "MacBook Air", "Mac Mini", "MacBook Pro"};

        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
        inputSearch = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.inputSearch);

        // Adding items to listview
        adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, R.id.product_name, products);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);

        /**
         * Enabling Search Filter
         * */
        inputSearch.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence cs, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
                // When user changed the Text
                MainActivity.this.adapter.getFilter().filter(cs);   
            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2,
                    int arg3) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub                          
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Layout Xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- Editext for Search -->
    <EditText android:id="@+id/inputSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Search products.."
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword"/>

    <!-- List View -->

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_view"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can accept my answer, in order to remove your question from the Unanswered Question Queue.

Answer (score 1):

You really need to use the [AutoCompleteTextView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AutoCompleteTextView.html) in place of the EditText.

An excerpt from the developer.android.com site:

```
public class CountriesActivity extends Activity
{
     protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
     {
         super.onCreate(icicle);
         setContentView(R.layout.countries);

         ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                 android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, COUNTRIES);
         AutoCompleteTextView textView = (AutoCompleteTextView)
                 findViewById(R.id.countries_list);
         textView.setAdapter(adapter);
     }

     private static final String[] COUNTRIES = new String[]
     {
         "Britain", "Belgium", "France", "Finland", "Ireland", "Italy", "Iceland", 
         "Germany", "Greece", "Spain", "Sweden", "Portugal"
     };
 }
```